# Wordpress hook to pre-populate the content field on post-new.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin which will help administrate a question-answer database. 'Candidate' questions are stored in a custom DB, and I'm working on a function by which a user can promote a db question to a fully fledged knowledgebase article (custom post type).

**I'd like to populate the content field on post-new.php based on the content of my $_POST data**, so a user can click a 'promote' link associated with a candidate and have the information already there.

**What's the appropriate filter hook to use for this**, or is there a better way?

*Edited title for clarity

Comment: I'm kind of looking at the edit_post_{$field} filter, but I'm not really sure how to use it. http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post_%7B$field%7D

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer my own question, but I found that I was looking for the 'the_editor_content' filter hook.

Comment: +1 so you come nearer to that point ;) Yes that hook sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the filter hook I was looking for is **the_editor_content**, which will (as its name suggests) let me manipulate the content that gets placed in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure I have grasped your point, but if the difference between an Q and A entry and a KB entry is more than just a flag in the table, eg it is a largely a copy operation from one table to another: Couldnt you simply use Mysqls INSERT INTO ability? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html 
which is triggered by the user posting back just the id of the Q and A article?

Comment: This isn't really a database structure question, just a wordpress hook question. I want to insert some arbitrary data into a field on post-new.php

Comment: doh, sorry - didn't notice the tags you set on the question - not a WP fan I'm afraid - I shan't remove the reply for fear of busting something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hook into default_content like this

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {

   $content = "This is my default content!";

   return $content;
}
```

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223801/the-editor-content-filter-change-the-content-of-other-textarea-in-wp-admin-in-ad)